# Git stored credentials work locally but don't have effect if logged into the machine via SSH

Tags: keychain, ssh, git

I have a remote macOS machine with git and GitHub Desktop installed, as well as my SSH public key.

If I connect to the machine via Screen Sharing, open a shell window and try e.g. `git pull` in my repository it works fine and doesn't ask for the credentials.

However, if I connect to the same machine using SSH and try the same git command, it asks for credentials every time (and works if I give it the correct username and password).

I tried a few suggestions such as [this one](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/caching-your-github-password-in-git) but everything I do doesn't seem to have any effect when connecting to the machine via SSH.

Is there some sort of a policy of not updating the KeyChain via SSH? Or is it something else?

P.S. I added this to my `~.ssh/config`:

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
```

Doesn't seem to help.

Also, my git URL is `https://github.com/...`

Comment: What happens if you try with an SSH URL instead of an HTTPS URL from GitHub?

Answer (score 1):

Add `ForwardAgent yes` to your ~/.ssh/config under the `UseKeyChain` line

Comment: Nope, same thing :(